# MySQL Workbench: 'Service Started then Stopped'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I know this has been asked before, but I've read the answers and haven't been able to find a solution.  MySQL server 8.0 fails to connect to server when I log on.  So, I checked the connection is "services" option on my computer - when I try to start connection, it says the connection has started and then stopped.  I then opened cmd as administrator, navigated to:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

and used this command:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --initialize
```

I get this message, and still no luck.

```
2019-01-23T22:42:52.046924Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) initializing of server in progress as process 25452
2019-01-23T22:42:52.051513Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-01-23T22:42:52.062075Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-23T22:42:52.064073Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

What else can I try?

Comment: The server tried to start then encountered an error. Check the error logs, it should tell you why. Chances are it's this folder: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\`

Comment: I edited my original post to include the error message: --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.   What would the issue be with the folder you mentioned?  That particular folder is not mentioned in the CMD error.

Comment: This folder should have your error logs. From there you can see what really went wrong.

Comment: Here we go:   Activation of app microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!ppleae38af2e007f4358a809ac99a64a67c1 failed with error: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: Is this something related to permissions?  I already renamed the 'data' folder 'data1', based on comments I've seen.  Hope that didn't screw anything up.

Comment: There is also this in the error log.  Faulting application name: LogonUI.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xccf07184
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.1446, time stamp: 0x22b27d6d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000bcbb
Faulting process id: 0x51c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4b36da2b3edbf
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogonUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 7907bef2-6da1-4a9d-afe7-c8bf504be3d4
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: You may have to update the [group policy on your machine](https://appuals.com/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy/). Hopefully this helps.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  I tried the first solution here; no luck.  As for the second option presented, I'm nervous to go about deleting policies in the registry editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're running mysql --initialize command.

The --initialize parameter is for creating basic files on data folder. It's only needs to be executed the first time for creating some basic files.

Also, the error message are telling you the same thing:

```
2019-01-23T22:42:52.051513Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
```

Get out the parameter and then all will work without problems. Or, if you need to create a new data directory, change the data dir on my.ini, or delete the current dir (THIS DELETES ALL YOUR DATABASES, CAUTION).

Comment: Thank you Sakura.  I'm a little confused - what are you suggesting I do specifically? What does "get out the parameter" mean?

Comment: Execute mysqld, not mysqld --initialize. These parameter should only be used for creating a new data folder.

Comment: I ran mysqld --execute.  It doesn't log an error, but "services" on windows is still reading "The MYSQL 80 service on Local Computer Started and Stopped".

Comment: Also, I have no idea where "my.ini" file is .  Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Then, create one and pass it by parameter to mysqld

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't really helpful.  The issue is still not solved.  I've run mysqld --execute in cmd, as you've suggested, and the server is still stopped.